# Multi Table in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I'm trying to make a strongly typed `"Create View"` so I could insert data into two tables simultaneously. However, when I create the view, the fields from my table are not included in my model. Can you tell what is the right way of doing this?

**My Table Model:**

```
public partial class CanaClie0012
    {
        public string Client00130012 { get; set; }
        public string F1Pais00200012 { get; set; }
        public string F1Cana02530012 { get; set; }
        public string Direcc0012 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TmStmp0012 { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Clientes0013
    {
        public string Client0013 { get; set; }
        public string Nombre0013 { get; set; }
        public string F1Pais00200013 { get; set; }
    }
```

**My Custom Model to combine the two table is:**

```
public class ClientModel
{
    public IQueryable<CanaClie0012> CanaClie0012 { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Clientes0013> Clientes0013 { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller: (Not really sure if im this correctly)**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClientCreate(CanaClie0012 canaclie0012, Clientes0013 clientes0013)
{
    ClientModel vm = new ClientModel();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.CanaClie0012.Add(canaclie0012);
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Clientes0013.Add(clientes0013);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

**My view:**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ClientModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ClientCreate";
}

<h2>ClientCreate</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ClientModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Client Name
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client00130012)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client00130012)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Pais
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.F1Pais00200012)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.F1Pais00200012)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Address 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Direcc0012)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Direcc0012)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre0013)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre0013)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big problem is that your view is strongly-typed to your `ClientModel` class.  This class does not include the members that you are referencing in your view.  Instead, that class includes lists of objects that include those members.  At this point, your view probably doesn't even compile.

Try changing your `ClientModel` class as follows:

```
public class ClientModel
{
  public CanaClie0012 CanaClie0012 { get; set; }
  public Clientes0013 Clientes0013 { get; set; }
}
```

then your view would reference the members such as:

```
<div class="editor-label">
  Client Name
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CanaClie0012.Client00130012)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CanaClie0012.Client00130012)
</div>
```

similarly for members of your `Clientes0013` members.

One additional thing:  you don't need to call `db.SaveChanges();` twice in your controller.  Instead, insert into both tables and do a single save:

```
db.CanaClie0012.Add(canaclie0012);
db.Clientes0013.Add(clientes0013);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you Matt Houser.. Its the answer im looking for.